# grass particle system spinning

Tags: modifiers, particles, simulation-nodes

I have been working on a project , I used a grass model , and I wanted the grass particle to react to the turbulence and the wind force , so I can make a realistic grass wind , but the grass , but some of the particles are spinning around which is very ugly I basically tried everything and searched the internet did not find this specific issue , I would really love to know how to fix the issue to make at least a realistic grass , very thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood the behaviour of the particle system.

This

[image]

is your particle.

But this is one object and has one pivot point, which Blender then tries to bend and rotate.
And of course this looks not that good.

If you delete (or separate and use collection) all except one blade of grass and move it so that the origin is at the bottom, apply scale and rotation, you will get:

[image]

[image]

I changed of course the number of particles, children, adapted the forces and animation.

Here the adapted file:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/03wjp6p8dg3x71fgvnh2x/particle-system-1.blend?rlkey=2ooiay9gy8oskwtlrq6zziybr&dl=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is actually a very good info , thank you for that